# How to search for consecutive special characters in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

I would like to find and replace parenthesis (used for in-text citation) as well as the preceding space.

I know the special character for white space is `^w` and I know how to find all parenthesis using `\(*\)`. The problem is that I don't know how to combine or concatenate the special characters. How do I find and replace all instances of  `(some text)` (there is a space in front of the opening parenthesis) with nothing?

I'm trying to do word count. Replacing `\(*\)` with nothing leaves a white space in front of a period, because I usually put a space between in-text citation and the preceding text. The space in front of the period causes the period to be counted as a word.

I'm not sure if operating system makes a difference, but I'm using a Mac.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with either of the two:

```
^s\(*\)
[^s ]\(*\)
```

where

- `[^s ]` - matches either a nonbreaking space (`^s`) or a space
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `*` - any text
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ^w in a *wildcard* Find expression.

Depending on your Windows regional language settings, the safest *wildcard* Find construction to find both the content between the parens and the preceding space(s) is:

```
[^s ]{1,}\([!\(]@\)
```

or:

```
[^s ]{1;}\([!\(]@\)
```

That because, if you have nested parens, an expression like:

```
[^s ]\(*\)
```

will find up to the first closing nested paren, leaving an orphaned outer paren in its wake.

Do note that, if you have nested parens, you will need to do the Find/Replace as many times as there are levels of nesting.